# How to prove this function is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to solve this question:

[image]

In order to solve this question above, I found this function: $r/w\mapsto (r/s)/(w/s)$ such that $w/s\in T$, I almost proved this map is an isomorphism, I'm stuck just in the surjectivity part.

If we get an element $(r/s)/(w/s)$ of $T^{-1}(S^{-1}R)$, ok! 
However, an element of $T{^1}(S^{-1}R)$ can be for example $(r/s_1)/(w/s_2)$ with $s_1\neq s_2$

I need help in this part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that in $S^{-1}R$ we have $(ws_1)/(s_1s_2) = w/s_2 \in T$, so $ws_1 \in S_*$. Now consider $rs_2/ws_1 \in S_*^{-1}R$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an element $z$ of $T{^1}(S^{-1}R)$, we can write it in the form

$$
z=\frac{\frac{r}{s_1}}{\frac{w}{s_2}}
$$

with $r,w\in R$, $s_1,s_2\in S$ and further $\frac{w}{s_2} \in T$.

Let $w'=s_1\frac{w}{s_2}$. Then $\frac{w'}{s_1}=\frac{w}{s_2} \in T$, so we deduce
that $w' \in S_{*}$. Finally $z=\frac{r}{w'}$ with $r\in R,w'\in S_{*}$.

Comment: How do you define this multiplication $w'=s_1\frac{w}{s_2}$?

Comment: Second, are you saying that an element $w'$ of $S_*$ is equal than other element $s_1(w/s_2)$ of $T$?

Comment: @user42912 $s_1$ and $\frac{w}{s_2}$ are both elements of the ring $S^{-1}R$, so multiplying them makes sense.

Comment: @user42912 The element in $T$ is $w/s_2$, not $s_1(w/s_2)$.